# Dynamic graph that changes with time? Is it possible with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, graph

I have some data that I was wondering I could graph with time? 
Basically first "graph" would be at time 0 which for example would be X vs Y, then second "graph" would be at time 0.5 seconds which is again X vs Y etc..

Maybe this will help explain my case:

```
Time (s)        X           Y
0               1           1
0.5             2           2
1               3           3
1.5             4           4
2               5           5
2.5             6           6
```

So according to the table above the values I want to graph are X vs Y, but I have so many time points of X & Y. Is it possible with VBA to produce an animation of X vs Y that loops through all the time points I have?

I tried to google alternatives but didn't find what I want, maybe Im looking in the wrong place? Is it possible with VBA? If not is there any software that can do this for me? The graph doesnt have to update automatically, I dont mind pressing a button for it to jump to the next time interval (Without creating a new graph).

Comment: Do you want x vs. y or do you want both x and y vs. time? In other words, do you want two curves or one?

Comment: One curve, x vs y.. but I want to show how it changes with time.. Is it possible? Still struggling to do using Power view but Im stuck :(

Comment: There are many ways. One way is to have the chart series be tied to named ranges and then have VBA change the reference of those names in a loop. Another way is to have the chart series point to an initially blank region and then successively populate that region in a loop. It is best to fix the minimum range and maximum range of each axes ahead of time, otherwise they update too much. You might need to throw a `DoEvents` into the loop so that it updates smoothly. I do a fair amount of chart animation, but it is getting late where I live. If I have time I'll try to post something tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am very new to VBA and I am completely puzzled to how I can start. I have a general idea but was thinking if there is a function that can make the jump between the time intervals smooth? I can imagine them running too fast after each other that my eye cant notice the different time intervals? Is there a pause function or something similar.. if you can post an example tomorrow would help a ton! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Power BI Designer (and the Power BI service, of course). The Scatter chart in that tool can take a value for the play axis, so the data can be played as an animation.

You could also use Power View in Excel 2013. I created a Power View scatter chart in Excel 2013 and clipped the animation to [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YFU_kVvKgc).

A sample file with a Power View and several series with a play axis can be accessed on my [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=FE479525195477F7!8056&authkey=!ABzX83Z7_VYIXb4&ithint=file%2cxlsx)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know if I succeed :), I am graphing a graph not a point like in your example but I guess its possible too! :) thanks again!

Comment: Couldnt do it with PowerBI or Power view :(

Comment: A sample file is on my [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=FE479525195477F7!8056&authkey=!ABzX83Z7_VYIXb4&ithint=file%2cxlsx)

Comment: Oh I see, is it possible to graph a line chart that changes with time? like several points connected with a line then add a play axis thats time? The line would change shape with time?

Comment: You can plot several data points for a time value, but in the Power View scatter plot they won't be connected with a line. I've updated the sample file and added several series to the chart.

Comment: Oh that sucks.. I guess I have to find a way with VBA to change the data of a chart with time? Thanks for your effort!